# Dell touchpad not working in ubuntu

Tags: dell, touchpad

I just downloaded Ubuntu and it looked great, but my touchpad wouldn't work... My computer is a Dell and I'm a newb at this sort of stuff so if someone could help me, please?

Comment: Which Ubuntu release? Which Dell?

Answer (score 2):

The things we need to know are:

- The **Version of Ubuntu** you are trying to install --> different Kernels, different setting, different solutions.
- The **Model number of the Dell computer** that you are using --> Helpful to determine the problem.

Nonetheless, this might help:

```
# modprobe -r psmouse
# modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Comment: Hi! The version of ubuntu is 13.04, and my laptop is a Dell Inspiron 15r n5110! I'm on my other dell laptop at the moment which isn't that great, so if I could get the touchpad working on my main one it'd be stress relieving.

Comment: Do the above commands help? What is the result?

Comment: Obviously they don't work otherwise I wouldn't of replied back.....

Comment: @Somu I had the same problem (14.04, vostro 5470) and these two lines fixed it. Thanks!

How do I make this change permanent?